# spacing in HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

I came across a task that requires writing HTML or CSS code. How can i make spaces or set the positioning?
My task is to make the page look like this:

```
report1                                               report2
report3                                               report4
report5                                               report6
```

after reading and looking around i tried this code

```
<font size=3>
 <a  href="http://obi-dev.jr.local:9704/analytics/saw.dll?bipublisherEntry&Action=open&itemType=.xdo&bipPath=%2FPrototype%2Fprice%20testing%20report.xdo&path=%2Fshared%2FPrototype%2Fprice%20testing%20report.xdo">
Price Testing Report </a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a  href="http://obi-dev.jr.local:9704/analytics/saw.dll?bipublisherEntry&Action=open&itemType=.xdo&bipPath=%2FPrototype%2Fprice%20testing%20report.xdo&path=%2Fshared%2FPrototype%2Fprice%20testing%20report.xdo">Price Testing Report 
     </a> 
</font>
```

so my question is, is there any substitue of the &nbsp for tabs ?
and is there a way to make it auto the positioning ?

Please be  as detailed as you can because I don't have a clue about HTML.
thanks all in Advance

Comment: Please don't create multiple IDs to submit the same question under: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516549/spacing-in-html-or-css

Comment: There is literally no code/markup here to actually check against to see what you've done. Also looks like you deleted your old post and made a new one, because I remember looking at this exact post about 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @j08691: It's the same user...

Comment: i deleted the old one and added the code to this one, the code should be shwoing i will double check why

Comment: Don't delete the old one. Edit it instead. It's not OK to repost questions as new.

Comment: @BoltClock - ah yes, my mistake about the second ID.

Comment: good for both of you the greatest conclusion ever

Comment: see how much better the response is when you provide code? Try not to be so snide in comments. I was one of the few that was helping you, even if my comments didn't seem so encouraging. This site is very useful if you follow a small protocol. Demonstrate effort by posting code, and also as you can see here, try not to repeat the same questions. You didn't get flamed this time but it can happen easily. The higher your reputation the more likely people will jump in and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to use a simpler method without tables so this is NON table solution and alot simpler for anyone who wants a non table method:

CSS:

```
//adjust the numbers how you see fit

.box{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.push{
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"> Hello </div><div class="box push"> Hello </div> <br/>
<div class="box"> Hello </div><div class="box push"> Hello </div> <br/>
<div class="box"> Hello </div><div class="box push"> Hello </div> <br/>
```

Working Example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/y62zp/2/**

Comment: Dave
this is exactly what i was looking for and want, not too complicated but looks organize
thank you so much for your help and sharing the code, really appreciate it and you saved me
thanks again

Comment: No problems :) Please tick my answer if it helped.

Comment: This is the most ideal solution. You can also wrap the `box` elements around a parent div and set the widths to 50% (or whatever tab size you want to separate it by) to always have it autofix. Updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/y62zp/4/)

Comment: is there anything i can use instead of &nbsp; that do the same result as an tab ?

Comment: Edit: use `<pre>` inside the div to preserve tabbed text.

Comment: i edited the  <pre> but its starting a new line

Comment: I would make a new question about it as its different issue to this question :)

Comment: its going to piss some people off dunno why
i will try and look around first
thank you again i really appreciate it

Comment: It won't just make the question clear and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` tags will preserve the spaces you want. It will also include any breaklines

```
<pre> 
Look      at     all    the spaces
and
the
break
lines
</pre>
```

As noted by Oberon  in the comments to this answer. Another method (which isn't as frowned upon) is using a table.

```
<html>
<body> 
<table border=1" > 
<tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Value 1a</td>
<td>Value 1b<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Value 2a</td>
<td>Value 2b<td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Which will give you this.
[image: Table Sample]

**EDIT Based on OPs comments**

 Using something as follows will help you align certain things or assign properties to your table or each "cell"

Table

```
 <table border=5" height="80" width="75%" bgcolor=#FAF93C style="table-layout: fixed; width: 75%">
```

Cell

```
<td align="left">This Text is aligned to the left</td>
```

Comment: thanks both of you for the helpful answers, is there a way to do it by specifying which position or point to start writing ?

Comment: @user2730114 you can mess with different properties of tables(ive edited). Or you can use seperate divs(completely diff method) to adjust the way peopel view your page.

Comment: @user2730114 the issue is i dont have experiance at all, am an oracle guy but i came cross that i have to make this code so the system populate this the context of the file and populate it into the page, all of the code will be written in text file
thanks though for explanation and help :)